# Проблемы с редактированием страницы сайта на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Всем доброго дня! Возникла проблема при редактировании сайта на wp. Скриншоты прикреплены ниже:
[image: так выглядит страница]

При нажатии кнопки редактировать страницу страница редактирования выглядит следующим образом:
[image: вид страницы в режиме редактирования]

Проблема заключается в том что раздел блоков сайта пуст и кроме надписи "Каталог" ничего не отображается. Прошу помочь если кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой. По моим подозрениям проблема с плагином PageBuilder.

Comment: Скорее всего это генерируемая страница. Разбирайся с тем, что у тебя делает этот каталог.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но прошу более конкретных инструкций)